# CloudFormation S3 Bucket/BucketPolicy creation - Unresolved resource dependencies [Environment] in the Resources block of the template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I recently started studying for my first AWS certification, and at the same time I have started playing with CloudFormation too. However, I hit a block.

**My problem:** I am trying to create an S3 bucket and to attach a Bucket Policy to it. However, whenever I try to validate the template, I get the following error:

```
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the ValidateTemplate operation: Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [Environment] in the Resources block of the template
```

**What I have done:**

```
  LogsBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Sub my-cluster-logs-${Environment}
      BucketEncryption:
        ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration:
          - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
              SSEAlgorithm: AES256
      PublicAccessBlockConfiguration:
        BlockPublicAcls: true
        BlockPublicPolicy: true
        IgnorePublicAcls: true
        RestrictPublicBuckets: true
      LifecycleConfiguration:
        Rules:
          - Id: Log expiry policy
            ExpirationInDays: 90
            Status: Enabled
          - Id: Change tier
            Status: Enabled
            Transitions:
              - StorageClass: STANDARD_IA
                TransitionInDays: 30
    DeletionPolicy: Delete

  LogsBucketPolicy:
    Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
    Properties:
      Bucket:
        Ref: 'LogsBucket'
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - s3:PutObject
            Resource: 
              - Fn::Join:
                - ''
                -
                  - !GetAtt LogsBucket.Arn
                  - '/*'
            Principal:
              AWS: #removed_for_this_post
    DependsOn:
      - LogsBucket
```

I have tried all kinds of things but I still get the error.

**Conclusion**
Any ideas? The template is a valid YAML template, by the way. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stick this at the top

```xml
Parameters:
  Environment:
    Type: String
```

And pass in a parameter name "Environment" from either your command or your deployment pipeline.

If you are say running a separate dev and production account you cannot just use the same bucketname since S3 bucket names must be unique worldwide, not just unique to your account.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more fiddling, I found the issue. I forgot to add the following code at the top of the template.

```
Parameters:
  Environment:
    Type: String
```